# How to run npm command with cron

Tags: npm, cron, nuxt.js

I use `Nuxt.js 3` and `nuxt-scheduler`

I want to make cron run once a week, cron will run the `npm run build` command. Please tell me how to specify the cron command?

```
import { useScheduler } from "#scheduler";


export default defineNitroPlugin(() => {
    startScheduler();
});

function startScheduler() {
    const scheduler = useScheduler();

    scheduler.run(() => {
        console.log("Start...");
    }).everySecond();
}
```

Or can someone suggest a better way to run the `npm run build` command once a week?

Comment: I could be wrong about this but I think it's better if you take the action of `npm run build` yourself. They way I see it is that, it will cause issues in the future. Again, I could be wrong. :)